# Google Colab Blender render Error: cannot read file

Tags: google-colaboratory, blender

Trying to render a single frame
following this script "Blender_script_for_Google_Colab_using_the_GPU.ipynb"
by- https://github.com/donmahallem

Successfully mounted GDrive and installed Blender.
Executed all the cells from top to bottom, one by one.

This is the OUTPUT of final Cell

````
found bundled python: /content/blender2.83.12/2.83/python
Error: Cannot read file '/content/{/content/drive/MyDrive/Blender/donut.blend}': No such file or directory
<bpy_struct, CyclesPreferences at 0x7f6366c38ba8>
Device found CUDA
Activating <bpy_struct, CyclesDeviceSettings("Tesla T4")>
Activating <bpy_struct, CyclesDeviceSettings("Tesla T4")>

Blender quit```
````

Comment: Please don’t edit a question to say it has been answered - just accept an answer (also vote on answers to show what was useful or not to you)

Answer (score 2):

**ANSWER**

It should be like this

`!/content/blender2.83.12/blender -P './setgpu.py'  -b -noaudio '/content/drive/MyDrive/Blender/donut.blend' -E CYCLES -o '/content/drive/MyDrive/Blender/test_mixed_####.png' -f 1 |& tee '/content/drive/MyDrive/Blender/log.txt'`

NOT like this

`!/content/blender2.83.12/blender -P './setgpu.py'  -b -noaudio '{/content/drive/MyDrive/Blender/donut.blend}' -E CYCLES -o '{/content/drive/MyDrive/Blender/test_mixed_####.png}' -f 1 |& tee '/content/drive/MyDrive/Blender/log.txt'`

In short I forgot to remove the curly brackets **{}** from "*Blend_file_path*" and "*Output_path*"

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use 'My Drive' rather than 'MyDrive' in your directory path.

Comment: ```!/content/blender2.83.12/blender -P './setgpu.py'  -b -noaudio '/content/drive/MyDrive/Blender/donut.blend' -E CYCLES -o '/content/drive/MyDrive/Blender/test_mixed_####.png' -f 1 |& tee '/content/drive/MyDrive/Blender/log.txt'```

Using this command it worked.